# Using transaction to swap two values- I dont think i can do this securely

Tags: security, transactions, firebase

I am trying two swap two valuues with firebase, and no matter what I do I cant seem to find anything thats secure.

UserA is in 23, userB is in position 5, I want to swap these two numbers..

obviously I should be using a transaction for this because one value is dependant on the other. At the moment I have my data set up like this-

```
-world
    -pos23
        -userA
    -pos5
        -userB
    -pos98
        -otherUser
    etc...
```

Obviously I could structure this differently- invert the users and position but it doesnt seem to help my problem which is-

If I want to do a transaction on these two users I have to apply it to "world", I cant apply it to a position because I need access to the other position. To do a transaction I have to provide read and write access to the whole world, which means any sort of security rules I apply to the way the data is modified at the lower level is useless- the world level read and write overrides it. What if i want to make it so userC cant be moved at all.

From my experiments this security rule invalidates any transaction i do, -

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "$anyPosition": {
      ".write": true,
    },
  }
}
```

I would think that grants access to anything in the structure, but it actually fails because I dont have a write:true at world level. It lets me use set but not transaction.

I might be going about this the wrong way, **how should I be swapping two values securely?**

Comment: Im not really sure why why my question was downvoted. Thats ok, I think I can use it by granting .read and .write access to everything, then using .validate on the transaction. Id still be interested in hearing others opinions on swapping values.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct that you can't access both values in a single operations while using two separate paths. No surprises there; the op has to be on `world`.

It does seem like [priorities](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html), might be a better solution than actually having to move user records in the data. But I don't fully understand your use case, so I won't question your reasons, just point them out in case they haven't been considered.

I'm sure you've realized that you could brute force a non-atomic approach, suitable for most everything but money and video game scores, by simply swapping them directly:

```
function swapValues( ref, keyA, keyB ) {
   ref.child(keyA).once('value', function(snapA) {
      ref.child(keyB).once('value', function(snapB) {
          snapA.ref().set(snapB.val());
          snabB.ref().set(snapA.val());
      });
   });
}
```

With only a slight edit, you can get both ops in a single blow, in an atomic/transaction-safe manner, by using [update](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/update.html):

```
function swapValues( ref, keyA, keyB ) {
   ref.child(keyA).once('value', function(snapA) {
      ref.child(keyB).once('value', function(snapB) {
          var updateVal = {};
          updateVal[ snapA.name() ] = snapB.val();
          updateVal[ snapB.name() ] = snapA.val();

          ref.update( updateVal );
      });
   });
}
```